# Why is an acoustic wave considered as a discontinuous solution in gas dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics

I don't have much knowledge on gas dynamics but I read that acoustic wave is discontinuous solution since properties ahead and behind the wave are different but the equation of a sound wave is a sine wave as I remember so why is it discontinuous?

Comment: I think you need to say *where* you have read this, if you want an answer.  It sounds more like a statement about shockwaves than about sound waves.

Comment: I came across it in a lecture video and I also read it in a book named fundamentals of gas dynamics., the exact statement was "when points 1 and 2 are located across a wave (say, a sound wave or shock wave),the derivatives of the ﬂow properties will be discontinuous" , where 1 and 2 are 2 points over which the basic 1- d flow equations (for frictionless, adiabatic, steady, one dimensional ﬂow of a calorically perfect gas.) were integrated.

Comment: That sentence makes little sense, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acoustic wave may indeed be considered as an infinitesimally weak shock wave (see *Fundamentals of Aerodynamics* by J. Anderson, for example), in the sense that fluid properties (pressure, for example) change by an infinitesimal amount across the acoustic wave. It obeys the usual wave equation (see [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave_equation)) precisely because it is a small amplitude wave.

It is not true that the wave equation allows only sinusoidal solutions. For example, the general solution of a 1-dimensional non-dispersive wave equation is $F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$, where $F$ and $G$ are **arbitrary** functions; sine wave is just one among several possibilities. Here $x$ is spatial coordinate along the direction of propagation, $t$ is time and $c$ is phase speed of the wave.